# Center of mass and stability of cars

Tags: kinematics

[image]

Why is it that most everyday cars have an engine and the center of mass in the front?
With my limited knowledge in physics, my understanding is that pulling an object is much easier than pushing due to stability reasons and the car with com placed in the front(second diagram) should be much more unstable, but this is seen in everyday cars.

Why don't all cars have the engine and the center of mass near the back wheels for stability? I feel there is a flaw in my understanding.

Comment: In what respect to you are saying stable. Please elaborate?. If i am guessing right then you are thinking of the toppling case where center of mass at the center is most stable. Is it So

Comment: @PranavAggarwal not really able to explain it but it's like driving a cargo truck forwards is much easier than driving it backward small deviations will cause the entire container to swerve to one side

Comment: So that factor must be friction

Comment: friction would be greater on the wheels where there will be COM

Comment: Now so your doubt is actually much different from concept of position of centre of mass this is because as the people beseated in the car the COM would be shifter to centre most probably

Comment: The design of cars is an engineering decision - ie a compromise between a range of factors, some of which have nothing to do with physics. See eg https://www.buyacar.co.uk/cars/775/front-wheel-drive-vs-rear-wheel-drive